# Get all users from role and add to dropdown (select) - wordpress, javascript

Tags: functions, javascript, user-roles, forms, dropdown

I have a shortcode from functions, which retrieves a list of all users from active role. I have managed to get the list into the dropdown list with a little trickery if I wrap a div around the users and name it userdiv.

The problem is that no matter how I try to get the users into the list, they either show up as one choice (all users) or all the letters show up as a separate choice.

I have this in functions:

```
function userLooping($role)
{
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => $role ) );

// User Loop
if ( !empty( $user_query->results ) ):
        echo '<div id="userdiv">';
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ):
        echo '"';
        echo $user->display_name; // display user name
        echo '",';  
    endforeach;
        echo '</div>';
endif;
}
add_shortcode( 'users_role', 'userLooping' );
```

I have put in `[users_role]` to fetch the users to the page (may not need this).
The dropdown has ID `input_5_13`

Script to get the users to the dropdown:

```
       <script>
            
            var select = document.getElementById("input_5_13"),
                     arr = [document.getElementById("userdiv").innerHTML];
             
             for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
             {
                 var option = document.createElement("OPTION"),
                     txt = document.createTextNode(arr[i]);
                 option.appendChild(txt);
                 option.setAttribute("value",arr[i]);
                 select.insertBefore(option,select.lastChild);
             }
             
        </script>
```

When the script collects the text from `userdiv`, it ends up as an option. A long line. If I remove `[ ]` from the script, all letters are fetched as an alternative.

Tried adding `"` before each user and `","` after, but I can't get it to work.

If I enter it manually in the script, it works. Then each user is added as a choice.

```
var select = document.getElementById("input_5_13"),
                      arr = ["user1","user2","user3"];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Got it working. Don't know if it's the right way to go though. Removed `echo '",';` from shortcode and inserted instead
`echo '<option value="zo">';`
`echo $user->display_name; // display user name`
`echo '</option>';`

The problem, however, is that everyone gets value zo.

Comment: Script:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>
        
$(document).ready(function () {
    where data =
      [];
    for (var index = 0; index <= data.length; index++) {
       $('#input_5_13').append('<option value="' + document.getElementById('divuser').innerHTML + '">' + + '</option>');
    }
});
         </script>`
Now all the choices come up as they should in the list.

Comment: It looks like I'm commenting my own comments :) The script is adding ALL members to the page. I just want it to put in the **members of the current user's role.** Does anyone have any idea? Guess I have to change something in the functions code section to get it right?